# how to debug revel framework(golang) application in visual studio code(vscode)

Tags: revel

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "attach",
        "mode": "debug",
        "remotePath": "",
        "port": 2345,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "program": "revel.exe",
        "env": {},
        "args": [],
        "showLog": true
    },

]
```

}

how to debug revel framework(golang) application in visual studio code(vscode)
how to write the configuration file(launch.json)

Comment: Is this a question?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to debug a revel framework (golang) app in vscode.

1. Import revel project folder into vscode
2. Edit ~/.vscode/launch.json so that it looks like the following: (replace values in <> with values for your own local env.

`{
      "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app/tmp/",
            "env": {},
            "args": ["-importPath", "<project folder name>", "-srcPath", "C:\\Users\\<username>\\go\\src",  "-runMode", "dev"]
        }
    ]
}`

Note that -importPath should be the directory (relative to $GOPATH\src where your project lives)

Note that the value for -srcPath should match your $GOPATH\src directory (I'm running on Windows)

Once your launch.json is set up as so, you can start the app in deb mode and put breakpoints wherever you wish.

[image]