# Is it possible to debug go revel framework from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, revel

I'm trying to debug a revel app with visual studio but I can't get it to work.

I've seen this question [how to debug revel framework(golang) application in visual studio code(vscode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171432/how-to-debug-revel-frameworkgolang-application-in-visual-studio-codevscode) but no answers yet...

I've tried with this config:

```html
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "debug",
      "remotePath": "",
      "port": 2345,
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "program": "~/code/go/bin/revel",
      "env": {},
      "args": [],
      "showLog": true
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm getting this error:
`Failed to continue: "The program attribute must point to valid directory, .go file or executable."`

I think it must be the rebel binary the one to be run here, but I don't know how to pass the app path, should it go in "args"?

Comment: Any args you need to pass go in `args`, yes. There's [documentation available](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes).

Comment: Hi Zapico... maybe you need to point the path of `program` to go/bin/revel.d/your-app-folder/the-executable

Comment: Hi again... I am thinking about the compilation... revel is a framework that auto-reloads the executable file when you run it again, if you had changed something in the code (not on the deps)... but in this case I don´t know how could it work. Try and tell us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

1. Suppose that the `GOPATH` is `C:\Work\golang`
2. Revel project name is `myapp`, thus the location of the project (workspace) will be `C:\Work\golang\src\myapp`.
3. Make some changes to the controllers etc...
4. Run the application with `revel run myapp`, then press `CTRL+C` to exit. This step is necessary to generate corresponding go files. The generated file, i.e. the `main` package will be available under `${workspaceRoot}/app/tmp/main.go`
5. Configure `launch.json` as follows:

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Launch",
               "type": "go",
               "request": "launch",
               "mode": "debug",
               "remotePath": "",
               "port": 2345,
               "host": "127.0.0.1",
               "env": {},
               "showLog": true,
               "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app/tmp/",
               "args": ["-importPath", "myapp", "-srcPath", "c:\\work\\golang\\src",  "-runMode", "dev"]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
6. The important parts are `program` and `args` parameters, while the other parameters are unmodified.
7. Set `breakpoint` and start the `delve` debugger...

[image: Debug revel application]

### EDIT:

1. Setting `args` parameter to `["-importPath", "myapp", "-srcPath", "${workspaceRoot}/..",  "-runMode", "dev"]` also work, and I think this should work in other platforms (Mac, Linux) too.
2. The error message is related to `delve` issue. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/986

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!

My dev env is mac so it's not exactly the same but it seems its "almost there". Now I'm getting this error: `could not launch process: dial tcp :64821: getsockopt: connection refused
Process exiting with code: 1`

Comment: It seems its about my delve installation, I'll check it later. And this answer should be in Revel doc!!! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help @putu, I'm facing different problems now 
```["-importPath", "myapp", "-srcPath", "${workspaceRoot}/..",  "-runMode", "dev"]```

Comment: If I remove "-runMode" and "dev" from args, it runs, but it seems like it's not loading correctly some files (but it's debugging anyway, THANKS a lot), I think I have a problem with environments in revel or something...

Comment: Hello, I am able to show variable values in a floating windows, for a simple example like this(https://twitter.com/i/moments/880234757807898629), but not for a revel application, I can debug the revel app but not inspect the variables. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AlvaroDenisAcosta Perhaps the debugger (and) vscode integration still have some issues. Once I've succeeded to display variable as shown in [https://imgur.com/a/2dL8g](https://imgur.com/a/2dL8g), but later it won't works.